# Authentication and authorisation in an n-tiered architecture

Tags: c#, authentication, architecture, authorization, business-logic-layer

I need to be able to tighten my business layer - access to particular data.
The UI can make a call to the business layer and receive a userdetail. The UI can then call .Save() on a user and the business layer will call the data access layer to save the user.

Although, the problem here is that I don't just want any user to be able to receive a userdetail and call save - only authenticated users with that role of "admin". How would I go about this authentication/authorisation in my business layer/UI so I can achieve this?

I am using ASP.NET for my UI, and I've read into membership/role providers, but this just seems to be for the actual UI. I need to secure it at my business layer because in the future there could be a couple of different UI's. e.g. windows forms and Asp.net.

Thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: how do you communicate between your tiers?  WCF,  .net remoting, web services?

Comment: Class Library References, but in the future this might change

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you might want to research (if developing in .NET 3.5 / 4.0) is using [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx).

If you are insterested in keeping your authorization logic outside your web site (which I assume you would if you are expecting to use your business layer from more than 1 front-end) I would definitely recommend yaking a look at WIF. You can also integrate with Active Directory using [ADFS v2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/ad-fs-2-overview.aspx) (which is a server role in Windows Server 2008 R2).

Patterns & Practices has released a [guide](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/) which can be quite useful for digging into the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Role / Membership providers include storage and code level components you can re-use - they aren't just the UI.

For fine-grained access control (for example to specific functionality on a page) you can use the Enterprise Libraries.  You'll be able to re-use code to protect functionality both at the BL layer and in the UI layer.

The link you most want is this one: [Determining Whether a User Is Authorized to Perform a Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664571(v=PandP.50).aspx)

Also see:

- [What Does the Security Application Block Do?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664559(PandP.50).aspx)
- [DotNetJohn - Enterprise Library Security Block...](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=220)
- [Rule Based Security using Microsoft Enterprise Library and CAS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/enterprise_lib_CAS.aspx)

During earlier releases of the EntLibs, the Authorization Manager was a key component, but in more recent versions it's not a firm requirement, instead you can use an `AuthorizationRuleProvider`.
see: [Developing Applications Using Windows Authorization Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480244.aspx).

Filtering data is a bit more problematic depending on the complexity of your data, the amount of it and performance needs.

- One strategy is to have a simple DAL that returns everything, and prune out data the current user isn't allowed to see in the BL.
- Design a DAL that has some knowlegde of the roles your application uses: 
  `DAL.GetCustomersForAdmin()` and `DAL.GetCustomersForMember()` But this is a bit dangerous as you'll be tied to using those roles.
- Have a database / DAL that is security aware, and always returns only the data the user is permitted to see, via the same methods: `DAL.GetCustomers()`

Comment: I think this is what I want. It does look complex though

Comment: A lot of things look complex from the outside - but aren't so bad once you're in; and once you're up to speed you can re-use it anywhere - the first time might be slow, but subequent use's will be  much faster.

Comment: With a lot of data, the first strategy would in theory take much longer time duo to DB transfer, as you say the 2nd strategy is something I would not prefer, but how do you implement the 3rd strategy, would the only thing there be a DB with all the users set? 

What about a fourth strategy, where the BL is aware of the users access, and uses the DAL to get only the data the users have access to. A morph between the 1st and 2nd strategy?